# Copy sparcv9 directory contents? JDK 7 install on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, java

I have installed JDK 7 from archive on a Solaris 10 machine.

/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_25

Executing ./bin/sparcv9/java executes well. I've attempted to copy ./bin/sparcv9/* to ./bin. That is how previous versions of JDK are structured. The files copied over and they appear on the surface to be fine but ./bin/java does not find libraries. Can someone give me a tip on how to properly copy the files?

I'm attempting: cp ./bin/sparcv9/* ./bin/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Solaris system on hand to test this on. Try linking to the ./bin/sparcv9 binaries from ./bin

```
ln -s ./sparcv9/java java
```